# Whenever I plugin my laptop's charger, screen turns brighter and I don't want it, what's the solution?

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-supply, power, brightness

Whenever I plugin the charger screen gets more brighter, I want it to remain as it is (as it was before charging)

How to get this done?

Comment: what laptop model do you have? Processor model? Dedicated graphics or integrated ? It would be best if you'd edit this directly into the question

Answer (score 1):

Plug in your Laptop.

Go to Windows 10  Settings, System and right there, change Plugged in (AC) Brightness to a level you want. Take a look at Night Light Settings to ensure it is no higher than the setting you just made above.